# Server Returned HTTP status code 403 in genymotion

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

When I am going to download android emulator image file, it's returned with this error:
[image: HTTP 403 ERROR]

After I changed network HTTP proxy and port it didn't work at all.
In Linux, it works perfectly fine. But in Windows it always show this problem.

What to do to solve this problem ?

Comment: have you set up proxy in genymotion settings? Or in windows settings?

Comment: Yes, I did that on genymotion settings.. but Problem remains...